# Delete a sub-object level named selection set in 3ds Max. (python / maxscript)

Tags: python, 3dsmax, maxscript

Simply trying to delete a sub-object level selection set.

```
#basic example:
name = 'new_set'

obj = rt.selection[0]
objFaces = obj.faces
set_members = objFaces[name] = rt.getFaceSelection(obj) #create a new set based on the current face selection.

print (set_members, objFaces[name]) #okay, now how to delete an existing set?

#rt.deleteItem(objFaces, <index>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems straightforward in MaxScript:

```
obj = $
obj.faces["new_set"] = obj.selectedFaces
print(obj.faces["new_set"])
delete obj.faces["new_set"]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but that seems to delete the set members, while leaving the set intact. `print(obj.faces["new_set"]);
delete obj.faces["new_set"];
print(obj.faces["new_set"]);`

Comment: My workaround was to just empty the set using: `objFaces[name] = rt.BitArray()`